# Why is the button outside of the parent container?

Tags: html, css

Why is the button outside of the parent container?
The button shouldn't be outside of the container at all, because the container is always so high that all child elements fit in.

The problem can be fixed by simply pasting this line of code into my CSS. But the margin shouldn't normally be necessary.

```
.apply-link-container {
      margin-bottom: 5rem;
    }
```

Even if the solution seems simple. I've been on it for hours and don't know what I did wrong. The button should be inside the container.

```css
.bg-1 {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.apply-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #000;
}

.apply-section-text {
  max-width: 50rem;
}

.apply-section .apply-link-container {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.apply-section a {
  background-color: rgb(250, 187, 120);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.apply-section a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(241, 146, 44);
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="apply-section bg-1">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <div class="apply-section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo</div>
          <div class="apply-link-container"><a class="apply-link" href="#">button</a></div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: If you make the `<a>` element block-level it will stay within the parent and not overflow.

Comment: @Tanner Dolby your tip solved my problem. However, I don't quite understand why I have to turn the a element into a block element

Comment: @software When the element is inline, it will be positioned so that its text content aligns with the text line its placed on. When you then add your padding to it it will simply expand around the text but since it's still the text that is part of the document flow, it wont affect the containing element. If you instead set its display to `inline-block`, you'll still place it inline but it will be its box that becomes part of the document flow, so padding and any other box model styling **will** affect the containing element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) `<a>` element into a [block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) element, this way it creates a "block" and the `2rem` margin you gave the `<a>` elements parent isn't a making the content overflow out the bottom. Now the content stays within the parent containers content-box even with the top margin.

```css
.bg-1 {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.apply-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #000;
}

.apply-section-text {
  max-width: 50rem;
}

.apply-section .apply-link-container {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.apply-section a {
  background-color: rgb(250, 187, 120);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block; /* or inline-block */
}

.apply-section a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(241, 146, 44);
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="apply-section bg-1">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <div class="apply-section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo</div>
          <div class="apply-link-container"><a class="apply-link" href="#">button</a></div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this in your container class:

height: fit-content;